# In golang, what is nice format to write JSON and MySQL query string?

Tags: go, coding-style

It is really hard to read an extremely long string of JSON or DB query in golang source code.

JSON Example:

```
"{\"task\":\"send_sms\",\"t_id\":988110,\"req\":{\"node\":1,\"msg_id\":987654321,\"m_num\":\"+61433092888\",\"p_num\":\"Private\",\"msg\":\"Hello world.\"}}      "
```

DB Query Example:

```
dbQuery = fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO `ms_message` (`task_id`, `panel_phone_num` ,`user_mobile_num`,`message_content`,`receiver_node_id`,`modem_index`,`generate_datetime` ) SELECT * FROM (SELECT %d, \"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\", %d,%d,\"%s\") AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `ms_message` WHERE `receiver_node_id` = %d AND `task_id` = %d ) LIMIT 1", taskId, panelNumber, mobileNumber, messageContent, nodeId, modemId, dateTime, nodeId, taskId)
```

What way is nice to make above strings looks reader friendly?

Comment: Don't use a format string to build your SQL queries. I cannot stress how dangerous this can be. http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/

Answer (score 2):

You can use backticks to write a multiline [string literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals), like so:

```
json := `
{
    "hello": "world",
    "foo": "bar"
}`
```

https://play.golang.org/p/bU5q6tx8Jx

The backticks in your SQL example might be problematic, though...

Comment: Great!!! Thank you! I spend hours on manually format strings with stupid way yesterday.....